# Accent on í misaligned in bibliography / citation

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, accents

I'm facing a strange issue with the accents on accented characters in bibliography entries not being placed right. Consider the following MWE, where a cited author's last name is ,,Galí``:

```latex
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8
\begin{filecontents*}{biblatextest.bib}
@Book{Gali2015,
  author    = {Gal{\'\i}, Jordi},
  title     = {Monetary policy, inflation, and the business cycle: an introduction to the new Keynesian framework and its applications},
  year      = {2015},
  edition   = {2},
  publisher = {Princeton University Press},
  location  = {Princeton and Oxford},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=bath,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatextest.bib}
\begin{document}
    \noindent Here is a citation. Compare \cite[S.~123]{Gali2015}. 
    The author's name is Gal{\'\i}.
    \appendix
    \newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]%
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Compare how the accent is placed in the citation and the bibliography vs. in regular text:

[image: Example of misaligned accent on i in ,,Galí``]

I'm at a complete loss as to how or why this is happening, or how to fix it. I'd appreciate any help, pointers, tips, suggestions etc. Thanks!

Comment: Easiest is to avoid the bug by typing Galí directly in the bib file.

Comment: Regardless of the issue here since you are using the Unicode engine XeTeX and Unicode-aware Biber, you might as well migrate your `.bib` file to Unicode and avoid the awkward macro-ASCII-escapes (that may well have influence on kerning due to the - for TeX - superfluous brace group).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Biber translates `\'\i` into the Unicode sequence

U+0131  ı   LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I
U+0301  ́   COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT

It seems like the Latin Modern fonts do not like this (valid) sequence.

XeLaTeX uses directly

U+00ED  í   LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH ACUTE

which causes no problem with Latin Modern.

As workaround you can either use `\'i` or `í` in the `.bib` file. Both are treated as U+00ED by biber.

Actually the entire thing is independent of biber. If one uses these Unicode sequences directly in the `tex` file, one sees the same problems when Latin Modern is used. This is not the case for (some) other fonts:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
Gal{\'i}
Gal{\'\i}
Galı́ % U+0131 ı LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I  U+0301 ́ COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT
Galí % U+00ED í LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH ACUTE

\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
Gal{\'i}
Gal{\'\i}
Galı́ % U+0131 ı LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I  U+0301 ́ COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT
Galí % U+00ED í LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH ACUTE
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Just to know, you wrote *...are treated as U+00ED by biber*. Where we could find such kind of information?

Comment: @Sigur I don't know if this is documented anywhere. I found it experimentally, i.e. processing various `bib` file with biber and inspecting the resulting hex-sequences (taking UTF-8 encoding into account).

Comment: So this is a bug in Latin Modern, really. Should this be reported? (And if so, where?)

Comment: @chsk One can argue that it is a font issue, c.f. the update. You can always try to contact the [GUST font team](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/).

Comment: Biber converts the text in various ways to a standard format to do its sorting on, which is a good thing. But I think it's a problem that biber doesn't keep the *original text* around, as it is written in the bib file, and then uses that, but instead uses that canonical form. I have argued about this at https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/23 .

Comment: @pst Interesting. Using `texencoding=ascii` as mentioned in that thread solves the issue as well. But i am not sure about any side effects.